# How to set django formsets _all_ error from view?

Tags: django, formset

**Description :**

Okay, so formset is a set of forms. I basically have some number, or form where i get this number from and then i compare it to summed number from all the forms from the formset. That's why i do part of validation in a view. And if those numbers don't match i want to set error , not to a specific form in a formset, but to formsets **all** errors.

I have no problem setting ordinary forms error from the view :

```
form.errors['__all__'] = form.error_class(["Here is your error"])
```

But how do i assign **all** error to formset, and is this even possible, or i have to assign this error to forms within the formset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formsets also have an `errors` attribute that works identically to `form.errors`.

However, it sounds like you're trying to do validation in your view. You should add the custom validation to the formset itself using the `clean` method, and raise `forms.ValidationError` when the user input is invalid. [See the Django formset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation).